# Plain C implementation of 'Cumulative All' operation for R

Tags: c, r, ffi

I want to implement a *cumulative all* through R's C interface. I was able to hack something together that produces the correct results, but I have little idea what idiomatic C should look like. The code should be easy to understand, even if you don't know about R.

### Description

The *cumulative all* takes a `LGLSXP` (logical S-expression) input. The function should output a `LGLSXP` of the same length as the input, where each element represents whether all values up to this point were `true`.

The three valued logic works like this: 
`(true & false) -> false`, `(true & na) -> na`, `(false & na) -> false`

#### LGLSXP

A `LGLSXP` is a pointer to a struct that contains an `int` array that represents 3 valued logic with `0` as `false`, `INT_MIN` as `NA` and `1` as `true`. This array can be accessed with `LOGICAL()`. You can read about SEXPs [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#SEXPs).

## Code

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>

SEXP cumall_impl(SEXP x) {
  SEXP res = PROTECT(allocVector(LGLSXP, XLENGTH(x)));
  R_xlen_t n = XLENGTH(x);

  if (n == 0){
    UNPROTECT(1);
    return(res);
  } else {
    memset(LOGICAL(res), 0, n * sizeof(int));
  }

  int *p_x = LOGICAL(x);
  int *p_res = LOGICAL(res);
  p_res[0] = p_x[0];

  for (R_xlen_t i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    if (p_x[i] == TRUE)
      p_res[i] = p_res[i - 1];
    else if (p_x[i] == NA_LOGICAL)
      p_res[i] = NA_LOGICAL;
    else
      break;
  }

  UNPROTECT(1);
  return res;
}
```

### Remarks

- `PROTECT()` and `UNPROTECT()` are necessary to prevent R's garbage collector from interfering
- `LOGICAL()` accesses the underlying array of a `LGLSXP`
- `TRUE`, `NA_LOGICAL` etc are provided by the headers.

### Headers

- The most important definitions are in [Rinternals.h](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/include/Rinternals.h) and [R.h](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/include/R.h).
- The `NA_LOGICAL` is defined in [Arith.h](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/include/R_ext/Arith.h) and [arithmetic.c](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/arithmetic.c)
- I am not sure where/how `TRUE` and `FALSE` are really defined. Likely sources are [Boolean.h](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/include/R_ext/Boolean.h) and [Rdefines.h](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/include/Rdefines.h)

I am thankful for all suggestions, be it coding style, variable naming or critique to how I formulated my question

Comment: "everything else as true" and `if (p_x[i] == TRUE)` seems wrong.  I'd expect all values that are neither `NA_LOGICAL` nor `FALSE`, not just the one `TRUE`, to cause that `if()` test to be true.  If we can rely on 2's complement, perhaps `if (p_x[i] & INT_MAX)`

Comment: When you say "LGLSXP is implemented as an integer array...." do you mean "... `int` array...".  If so better to say `int`.  If not always an `int`, `sizeof(int)` in `memset(LOGICAL(res), 0, n * sizeof(int));` is suspicious.  I guess it comes down to it would make for  a more effective review with `<R.h>, <Rinternals.h>` posted or referenced.

Comment: Thanks. I added a link to [Rinternals.h](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/include/Rinternals.h) and [R.h](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/include/R.h) to the original question. I have since rewritten the code using the suggestions by Edward, but I am not sure if I should post the new code here or not. LGLSXP should only take the values TRUE, FALSE, NA_LOGICAL. If there are different values something is not right and the function should imho abort.

Comment: I figured out I am not 100% sure how TRUE is defined (but in C everything that does not evaluate to 0 evaluates to true, right?). I added some more links to headers that seemed relevant to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see some things that may help you improve your code.

### Use variables effectively

The code begins with this:

```
SEXP cumall_impl(SEXP x) {
    SEXP res = PROTECT(allocVector(LGLSXP, XLENGTH(x)));
    R_xlen_t n = XLENGTH(x);
```

However, there's not really any reason not to define and use `n` first:

```
SEXP cumall_impl(SEXP x) {
    R_xlen_t n = XLENGTH(x);
    SEXP res = PROTECT(allocVector(LGLSXP, n));
```

### Use all required `#include`s

The code uses `memset` and so it should also have this line:

```
#include <string.h>
```

Even though it happens to compile because some of the R libraries probably also include that, it's important to make sure that the code does not rely on undocumented interface assumptions.

### Use a single loop over all elements

The code uses `memset` to initialize all values to `FALSE` and then sets the first value explicitly and then loops through all other values.  I'd be inclined instead to recode that as a single `for` loop instead:

```
int prev = TRUE;
for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (p_x[i] == TRUE)
        p_res[i] = prev;
    else if (p_x[i] == NA_LOGICAL)
        p_res[i] = NA_LOGICAL;
    else
        p_res[i] = FALSE;
    prev = p_res[i];
}
```

Writing it this way avoids the need for the `if (n == 0)` construct and also eliminates the need for the `memset`.

**Note:** Ordinarily, we'd prefer to use a `switch` there instead of a chained `if..else` but we're prevented from doing so because `NA_LOGICAL` does not evaluate to an integer constant the way it's defined in R.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Some of those I should have caught myself (like the `n`).

Comment: Do you maybe have any more tips where I can look up where stuff like TRUE, NA_LOGICAL, etc are defined? is there a better way than just googling?

Comment: You can look up the definitions by reading through the `#include` files `R.h` and `Rinternals.h` but be aware that unless it's a documented part of the interface, it may well change.  Documentation is here: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/fullrefman.pdf